# python spark - filter rows in dataframe based in other dataframes line IN clause in SQL

Tags: python, apache-spark, select, dataframe

My main dataframe looks like:

```
data = spark.createDataFrame([
      ("name1", "type1", 2), 
      ("name1", "type2", 1), 
      ("name1", "type3", 4), 
      ("name1", "type4", 5),
      ("name2", "type1", 6), 
      ("name2", "type2", 7), 
      ("name2", "type3", 8) \
    ],["name", "type", "cnt"])
    data.printSchema()
```

what is:

```
|name  |type|cnt|
|------|-----------
|name1 |type1|  2|
|name1 |type2|  1|
|name1 |type3|  4|
|name1 |type4|  5|
|name2 |type1|  7|
|name2 |type2|  8|
| .... | ... |   |
```

Then there are two other dataframes that I want to use to filter the main DF:

```
df_name = spark.createDataFrame([
      ("name1"), 
    ],["name"])
    data.printSchema()


df_type = spark.createDataFrame([
      ("type1"),  
      ("type3")
    ],["type"])
    data.printSchema()
```

I would like to select all rows in df1 that have `name` IN df_name and `type` in df_type.
Similar to what in clause does in SQL

```
SELECT * from df1
WHERE name in ('name1') 
AND type IN ('type1', 'type3');
```

What should result in 2 rows:

```
|name  |type|cnt|
|------|-----------
|name1 |type1|  2|
|name1 |type3|  4|
```

How can it be done in an efficient way using **spark** dataFrames, is the performance better than doing it in Hive?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can inner join `data` with the `type` and `name` data frames:

```
data.join(df_type, ["type"], "inner").join(df_name, ["name"], "inner").show()

+-----+-----+---+
| name| type|cnt|
+-----+-----+---+
|name1|type3|  4|
|name1|type1|  2|
+-----+-----+---+
```

Comment: That's cool, how can I keep just one of the columns being merged?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but usually you can do that by pre select or rename columns before joining, something like `data.join(df_type.select("type"), ["type"], "inner").join(df_name.select("name"), ["name"], "inner")`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
df1 = data.join(df_name, 
          data.name == df_name.name, 
          "inner").join(df_type, 
          data.type == df_name.type, 
          "inner")
```